# stop Xserver in Xubuntu 11

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, x-server, xubuntu

I want to shutdown my X to be able to install proprietary NVidia driver, but I couldn't find out how. There are some suggestions that didn't work for me.

I neither have `/etc/init.d/gdm` nor `/etc/init.d/kdm` nor `/etc/init.d/xdm`, on which I could call stop or start.

`/etc/init.d/x11-common` commands seem to have no effect, neither does `init 2`.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xubuntu uses `upstart`, so you should use

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

or

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

depending if you are using Ubuntu 11.04 (or prior) or Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: thx! `service lightdm stop` does its job for me :) I know why I prefer stackexchange over ubuntuforums ;)

Answer (score 1):

check /etc/inittab and see if X is getting respawned everytime?. BTW, I would usually go to `init 3` myself to shutdown X and perform any X related configuration.
You can alternatively try to login into the other terminals provided with `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F2` or `F3` and make the changes in there rather while X is shutdown using `init 3`

Ubuntu uses `upstart` so Xubuntu might as well be. I tried looking elsewhere for this .. [ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1584286](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1584286)

Comment: init 3 seems to have no effect. So if I go to tty2 as root and enter init 3 nothing happens. I have on `ctrl+`alt`+`f7` the same xfce screen with windos open than before. I don't have `/etc/inittab` either to look at

Comment: `/etc/inittab` does not exist, you meant? sounds strange to me. Ubuntu uses `upstart` so Xubuntu might as well be. I tried looking elsewhere for this .. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1584286

Comment: Use `update-rc.d` to disable the gdm service and try a reboot. Perhaps it can take you to the text logins.

Comment: yes, `/etc/inittab` does not exist.